# How to use clojure files dynamically?

Tags: java, dynamic, clojure

I want use java code to run some clojure files dynamically which are in some zip files.

If the clj.p1.core.clj is on the class path, it can runs correctly.

```
require.invoke(Clojure.read("clj.p1.core"));
```

How to make it dynamically?That is, put clj.p1.core.clj in the a1.zip (maybe some files), the java program could select the zip and then run it?

Comment: I have tried Compiler.loadFile("./a.zip");RT.loadResource("./a.zip");doesn't works

Comment: Are those really ZIP files or JAR files like e.g. from MavenCentral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you should unzip those files first and then specify a `*.clj` file when invoking `Compile` class; take a look at [its sources](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compile.java).

What would be much better in your case is to compile a Java class from Clojure sources first and then load that class in Java as well. Just add a specific step into your build process that cares of it. In that case, your Java code will look much simpler and wont' waste time on loading Clojure code dynamically.

Creating a Java file would be easy; just wrap Clojure sources with additional namespace with `gen-class` declaration. Move its output into your Java project or specify classpath properly. See [gen-class page](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-class) for more examples.

Comment: thanks,I want to publish the new version of the program  with  the small zip packages of clj files.now have found the solution:firstly,create a classloader cl = new URLClassLoader(.."a.zip"...),then call compiler.LOADER.doReset(cl). It worked.